# Deploy an Angular 6 app on a server over HTTPS

Tags: angular, https, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I managed to serve my Angular 6 app in localhost over HTTPS with the help of [this article](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a).

Now I am trying to deploy my app on a VM in the cloud (Google Cloud Compute Engine) and I would like to make my app available over HTTPS too.

The steps I did:

1. Activate HTTPS trafic on the VM
2. In local: ng build --prod
3. On the VM: copy the dist folder to /var/www/html/

Works like a charm over HTTP but not over HTTPS. For the latter I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with angular

Comment: This is not related to angular of course. Are you sure you configured the firewall rule correctly? if so try restart machine. and check again.

Comment: I made sure that I configured the firewall to accept HTTPS request. I also restarted the VM. I figured it might be related to how I deploy the Angular app because it work over HTTP but not over HTTPS... so maybe I put the code in the wrong place or something else...